# Convert number of minutes to hh:mm

Tags: sql-server, time, blackboard

I have a column in a table that stores the number of minutes as a `numeric(18,4)` field named `[course_access_minutes]`.

The stored values come from a blackboard database and look like this:

```
0.0500
0.0667
0.3667
up to 
314.0833
625.8167
```

How do I convert these to time hh:mm, I've had a good look at the database documentation and all I can find is

course_access_minutes   numeric(18,4)   This is the number of minutes that the user accesses this course in total during this login session.

Can I assume that I can make a direct conversion from minutes into hours? I think I will take any values below 1 as 0 minutes. What is the best way to do this in SQL? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What would be the expected output from your sample data?

Comment: @Sean Lange sample data is as above, I want to convert to hh:mm e.g. (48:35 48 hours 35min)

Comment: Yeah, so what would be 0.0500 converted to hh:mm?    What would be 314.0833 converted to hh:mm?

Comment: Yes, but mostly concerned with values above 0.

Comment: please explain what will the value if 0.05 to 314.0833, which we verfiy while giving the answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(s, 625.8167 * 60, 0), 108)
```

If the duration is longer than 24 hours you can use this

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, CAST(1877.4501 * 60 AS int) / 3600) 
    + RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(s, 1877.4501 * 60, 0), 108), 6)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it's really neat! I've used CONVERT(time(0), DATEADD(s, 625.8167 * 60, 0)) as it's in the time format then.

Comment: Best answer found for this!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `FLOOR` like this

```
DECLARE @SampleData AS TABLE
(
    Minutes numeric(18,4)
)

INSERT INTO @SampleData
VALUES
( 0.0500),
( 1.0500),
( 30.0500),
( 80.0500),
( 314.0833),
( 625.8167)

SELECT CONCAT(floor(sd.Minutes/60),':', CASE    WHEN sd.Minutes - floor(sd.Minutes/60)*60 < 1 THEN '0'
                                                ELSE FLOOR(sd.Minutes - floor(sd.Minutes/60)*60 )
                                        END) AS hours
FROM @SampleData sd
```

Returns

```
hours
0:0
0:1
0:30
1:20
5:14
10:25
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, this worked also but have gone for the one line answer.

Comment: @Dafmeister Yes, but with the accepted answer,  you'll never get more than 24 hours

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH _Samples AS (
    SELECT CONVERT(numeric(18, 4), 0.0500) [course_access_minutes]
    UNION ALL SELECT 0.0667
    UNION ALL SELECT 0.3667
    UNION ALL SELECT 314.0833
    UNION ALL SELECT 625.8167
) 
SELECT 
    S.course_access_minutes, 

    -- split out the number
    FLOOR(S.course_access_minutes / 60) [hours], 
    FLOOR(S.course_access_minutes % 60) [minutes], 
    FLOOR((S.course_access_minutes - FLOOR(S.course_access_minutes)) * 60) [seconds], 

    -- to a string
    CONVERT(varchar(10), FLOOR(S.course_access_minutes / 60)) 
    + ':' + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(varchar(10), FLOOR(S.course_access_minutes % 60)), 2)
    + ':' + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(varchar(10), FLOOR((S.course_access_minutes - FLOOR(S.course_access_minutes)) * 60)), 2) [time_string], 

    -- You could consider converting to the time data type if the values will never exceed the limit
    -- time supports 00:00:00.0000000 through 23:59:59.9999999
    -- 0 through 1439.9833333 ... 23 * 60 = 1380 + 59 = 1439 + (59 / 60) = 1439.9833333 
    -- (see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/time-transact-sql)
    CONVERT(time, 
        CONVERT(varchar(10), FLOOR(S.course_access_minutes / 60)) 
        + ':' + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(varchar(10), FLOOR(S.course_access_minutes % 60)), 2)
        + ':' + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(varchar(10), FLOOR((S.course_access_minutes - FLOOR(S.course_access_minutes)) * 60)), 2) 
    ) [time]
FROM 
    _Samples S
```

(It wouldn't be difficult to further this idea and split out the fractional seconds as well.)

Which yields:

```
course_access_minutes  hours  minutes  seconds  time_string  time
---------------------- ------ -------- -------- ------------ ----------------
0.0500                 0      0        3        0:00:03      00:00:03.0000000
0.0667                 0      0        4        0:00:04      00:00:04.0000000
0.3667                 0      0        22       0:00:22      00:00:22.0000000
314.0833               5      14       4        5:14:04      05:14:04.0000000
625.8167               10     25       49       10:25:49     10:25:49.0000000
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that this is going to be like Greg's answer, but I wanted to explain and simplify it.

You have minutes, so dividing them by 60 and flooring it (removing the decimal) gives the hours (without the minutes).

If you take the total minutes again, and remove (mod it by) the floored hours - which requires conversion to minutes by multiplying by 60 - you are left with the remaining minutes by essentially just finding out what is left after taking away that many groups of sixties:

```
SELECT FLOOR(course_access_minutes / 60) as Hours,
(FLOOR(course_access_minutes) % 60) as Minutes
FROM MyTable
```

If you want the decimal to appear for the amount of minute fractions (you want the seconds to appear, in decimal form), remove `FLOOR`.

If you want seconds in real numbers, keep `FLOOR` and use what Greg had: `FLOOR((S.course_access_minutes - FLOOR(S.course_access_minutes)) * 60)` for seconds. Be careful with the parenthesis, though, because you can end up accidentally flooring your decimaled minutes and get 0, and then 0*60 is zero:

```
FLOOR(
    (
        course_access_minutes - 
        FLOOR(course_access_minutes)
    ) * 60
) as Seconds
```