# Getting HH:mm version of total minutes in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, sum

I have a column which is a sum of total minutes users spend on a task. This column was got using:

```
(sum(cast(LTRIM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, 0, TotalTimeOtherTasks))as int)) over (partition by headLogs.operatorID)/60) as TotalTimeOtherTasks
```

This returns e.g 315.
TotalTimeOtherTasks is a column of times for that task e.g 
00:30:23
01:05:55

I want to make this show in HH:mm format so, 315 = 05:15.

I've tried doing other answers for similar questions such as; using separate formulas and concatenating them but i get errors such as " '05:15' cannot be converted to an int " once it gets the answer or "':' is not recognized as part of the formula". If i convert it I then can't use sum(). So i think this might be its own question.

Comment: Database is Oracle, SQLServer, MySQL ... ? also please provide a small example table and expected result. Not only one example(like you did) but 2 or 3 data in the table (with TotalTimeOtherTasks and operatorID columns) and your expected results...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is to compute the minutes and seconds separately, and then concatenante them

```
concat(
    sum(datediff(second, 0, TotalTimeOtherTasks)) 
        over (partition by headLogs.operatorID) / 60,
    ':',
    sum(datediff(second, 0, TotalTimeOtherTasks)) 
        over (partition by headLogs.operatorID) % 60
) as TotalTimeOtherTasks
```

Note that I removed the casting, that seems unnecessary here: in most databases, `datediff()` returns a integer already.

Comment: that done it, thanks! Think I was just getting confused by all the examples I've seen and not executing them properly.

Answer (score 0):

Though the answer is already accepted, I will post my solutions which is working in MySQL.
Reference from here: [Convert number of minutes to hh:mm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44203036/convert-number-of-minutes-to-hhmm)

Assuming the following table structure

```sql
create table total_minutes(
    id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    total_time int,
    primary key(id)
);
```

```sql
SELECT total_time, floor(total_time/60) as hours, lpad(floor(total_time%60), 2, '0') as minutes,
concat(floor(total_time/60), ":", lpad(floor(total_time%60), 2, '0')) as hh_mm FROM classifiedads.total_minutes;
```

Gives

```sql
t   h   m   hh:mm
35  0   35  0:35
95  1   35  1:35
69  1   9   1:09
```

Comment: I think they are using SQL Server (based on the `DATEDIFF()` syntax in the question).